# Only update parameters where the value is specified by client

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a servicestack service which accepts a DTO that looks like this:

```
[Route("/appointment/{id}", Verbs = "POST")]
public class UpdateAppointment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Guid? MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I check whether the MemberId value was set by the client since "null" is a valid value. Normally if NULL is not a valid value, I could use the PopulateWithNonDefaultValues() method.

So the result should be that if I don't specify MemberId in my HTTP POST payload, I want the server to not update the value.

I hope that makes sense..

Comment: The `Route` attribute does not belong on a DTO.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Actually [Request DTO's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#custom-routes) is the only Type that `[Route]` attributes are allowed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normally an issue if you consider that the client always provides all values when calling the `UpdateAppointment` Service. So I'd highly recommend that you consider every property is a "valid" value provided by the client and update all fields.

Create a separate Service if only want to update a partial property list.

If I really needed to check whether the client provided a value you can specify a different value in the Request DTO constructor, e.g:

```
public class UpdateAppointment
{
    public UpdateAppointment() 
    {
        MemberId = Guid.Empty;
    } 
    //...
}
```

where a non `Guid.Empty` value means it was populated by the client.

Or you could also use a calculated Property:

```
public class UpdateAppointment
{

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool HasMemberId { get; set; }

    Guid? memberId;
    public Guid? MemberId 
    {
        get { return memberId; }
        set 
        {
            memberId = value;
            HasMemberId = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A more fragile alternative is to buffer the Request with the global Request Filter:

```
appHost.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
    httpReq.UseBufferedStream = true;
});
```

Which will retain a copy of the Request Stream which you can get a copy of in your Service with:

```
var jsonBody = base.Request.GetRawBody();
var hasMemberId = jsonBody.ToLower().Contains("memberid");
```

Although note this is serializer dependent, i.e. wont work with Binary Serializers like ProtoBuf or MsgPack.

Comment: Ah, I like the Request DTO constructor solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why is `MemberId` nullable if null value is not allowed?

Just change its definition to:

```
public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
```

Comment: null values are allowed, as mentioned in OP: IF null values are NOT allowed I could use PopulateWithNonDefaultValues()

Answer (score 0):

have you tried load the values first then editing it before update?

I mean this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(UpdateAppointment UAForm){
     UpdateAppointment ua = new UpdateAppointmentBll().Find(UAForm.Id);
     ua.StartTime = UAForm.StartTime;
     //so no...
     if(UAForm.MemberId != null)
        ua.MemberId = UAForm.MemberId;

     new UpdateAppointmentBll().Save(ua);

     return View();
}
```

Comment: I could check if it's "null" however "null" is a valid value, as there would be cases where I actually want to set the value to "null".

Comment: so check to see if the value was "changed"

if(UAForm.MemberId != ua.MemberId)

Comment: I can't do that either because when it's not specified (in the payload), I get "null" and "null" would be seen as different to what is stored.

Instead I need to ignore it completely if it's not in the payload.

Seems like there's no way around this but to make the parameter a "required" field so that the client should always send this up as part of the payload.